# Vertex representation haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm using [fgl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl) to represent my graph:

```
graph1 :: Gr Int Int 
graph1 = mkGraph (genLNodes 1 7)[(1,2,1),
                (2,3,1),
                (3,4,1),
                (3,5,1),
                (5,6,1),
                (5,7,1)]
```

Then I do

```
level 1 graph1
```

which returns

```
[(1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,3),(6,4),(7,4)]
```

and now I want to assign to each vertex X and Y coordinates, where X is the second value from the tuple. For example, for the tuple `(1,0)`, X=0. Y is not relevant, and could be 0 for now.

I don't know how to write it in Haskell; I would be very grateful for some help.

Comment: To help us understand the question, what result do you want for your example?

Comment: It sounds like you want to map over the vertices

Comment: I want to assign to each vertex x and y, and then display each vertex on the screen :)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Write a question that compiles:

```
import Data.Graph.Inductive
import Data.Graph.Inductive.Example
```

Step 2: Include enough words to help us understand what you are doing:

```
-- Construct a graph with node Ids from 1 to 7 and edges with ids
-- all set to '1'.
graph1 :: Gr Int Int.
graph1 = mkGraph (genLNodes 1 7)[(1,2,1),
                (2,3,1),
                (3,4,1),
                (3,5,1),
                (5,6,1),
                (5,7,1)]

main :: IO ()
main =
 do let l1 = level 1 graph1
    -- ^^ This is a breadth-first search of the graph starting at node '1'.
    print l1
    -- Output: [(1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,3),(6,4),(7,4)]
```

Step 3: State the desired end goal and attempts to reach that state.  Sadly you have shown no attempt to solve the problem.  Zero effort questions are generally discouraged here.  Even if you can't get things to work it is generally more productive to show your attempt - it serves as a focal point for learning and teaching.

My interpretation of your goal and solution is thus:

```
-- Now we want to assign each vertex an x and y value where 'x' is
-- taken as the 2nd element in the above-printed tuple - that is, the
-- 'x' value is the distance from the starting vertex which was '1'.
let xyGraph = map (\(nodeId,xVal) -> (nodeId,xVal,defaultYValue)) l1
    defaultYValue = 0
print xyGraph
```